# problems in writing x86 assembly code in visual studio 2012 on win 7 64 bit

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, assembly

I want to create an application that shows an array of character in console with x86 assembly language.
i write it in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Version. In addition my Windows is 7 64 bit.
When run it in compiler, I mean in visual studio, I've this error:

```
main.cpp(8):  error C2443: operand size conflict
main.cpp(11): error C2432: illegal reference to 16-bit data in 'second operand'
```

My code is:

```
void main(){
    char nameAndId[] = "name:mohammad mahdi derakhshani .\n";
    int sc=-1;
    while(nameAndId[sc++]!=0){
        _asm{
            push si
line 8:     mov si,sc

            xor edx,edx
line 10:    mov dl,nameAndId[si]
            mov ah,2
            int 21h
            pop si
        }
    }
}
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Well which line is line 8, and which line is line 11? You could at least be kind enough to show us which lines the errors occurred on.

Comment: The assembly code in your question is real-mode DOS code. I don't know if the linker that comes with Visual Studio 2012 even is capable of generating DOS executables, and you wouldn't be able to run the executable directly in Windows 7 anyway. I you really want to write DOS programs in assembly, use tools appropriate for the job (really old versions of `masm` should work, as should `tasm` and `nasm`), and get an emulator like `DOSBox` that you run the programs in.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `16-bit SI` register instead of 32-bit one `ESI`.

For the other side, I don't know if `int 21` still works but I recommend to get a pointer to `WriteConsoleA` api using `GetProcAddress` and call the api instead of using the old d.o.s. functions.

Third: When the loop begins, `sc` equal -1, so you reference `nameAndId[-1]`. Change `sc++` with `++sc`.

Comment: For assembly use 32-bit register when referencing addresses.

Comment: so how?would you repairing for me above code?comment it here.

Comment: Change `SI` with `ESI`

Comment: try `mov dl, nameAndId[esi]` although inline assembly is limited in some circumstances.